# sending a element target to iframe in hta

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

1st question - go easy :)

I want to display a html page in an iframe (name = "content"). The problem is that if I open in IE then this works, but if I open as a hta file then the href pops up as a new window.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Link to target iFrame</title>
<HTA:Application
 ID = "HTA"
 ApplicationName = "Test Link to target iFrame"
 Border = "thin"
 BorderStyle = "normal"
 Caption = "yes"
 ContextMenu="yes"
 Icon = ""
 InnerBorder="no"
 MaximizeButton = "yes"
 MinimizeButton = "yes"
 Navigable="yes"
 Scroll="yes"
 SrollFlat="no"
 Selection="yes"
 ShowInTaskBar = "yes"
 SingleInstance = "yes"
 SysMenu = "yes"
 Version = "1.0"
 WindowState = "maximize"
>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var main = function(){
        create_div_frame();
        createLink();
    }

    var create_div_frame = function(){
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = "content_div";
        document.body.appendChild(div);

        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.id = "content_frame";
        iframe.name = "content";
        iframe.src ="html/default.html";
        iframe.frameborder = "1";
        iframe.application = "yes"
        document.getElementById("content_div").appendChild(iframe);
    }

    var createLink = function(){
        var ul = document.createElement("ul");
        ul.id = "my_ul";
        document.getElementById("content_div").appendChild(ul);

        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.id = "my_li";
        document.getElementById("my_ul").appendChild(li);

        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.id = "my_a";
        a.href = "html/content.html";
        a.target = "content";
        document.getElementById("my_li").appendChild(a);

        var label = document.createElement('label');
        label.htmlFor = "my_a";
        label.appendChild(document.createTextNode("content"));
        document.getElementById("my_a").appendChild(label);
    }
</script>
</head>
    <body onload = main();>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Teemu on this thread.

[HTML tags does not in HTA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857014/html-tags-does-not-in-hta#autocomment43708830)

I added a doctype and x-ua-compatible to my page and it works now.